# Oracle concatenate in one column, display in multiple line

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation

I need to concatenate a few column into one and I'm using || to do that. The result successfully display all the data in one column. However, I need it to display in multiple line in that one column. Is that possible?

Here is my current code:

```
SELECT addr1 || CASE WHEN addr2 IS NOT NULL THEN ', '|| addr2 END               
             || CASE WHEN addr3 IS NOT NULL THEN ', '|| addr3 END               
             || CASE WHEN addr4 IS NOT NULL THEN ', '|| addr4 END               
             || CASE WHEN addr5 IS NOT NULL THEN ', '|| addr5 END AS Address
  FROM addressdata
```

And this is what I want it to display as:

[image]

I'm still new to this Oracle and database thing. Really appreciate your help.

Thank you in advance. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a comma (as a separator), use *newline* (`chr(10)`)  or - maybe even better - CRLF (carriage return line feed) `(chr(13) || chr(10)`) character:

```
SELECT addr1 || CASE WHEN addr2 IS NOT NULL THEN CHR(13)||CHR(10) || addr2 END               
             || CASE WHEN addr3 IS NOT NULL THEN CHR(13)||CHR(10) || addr3 END               
             || CASE WHEN addr4 IS NOT NULL THEN CHR(13)||CHR(10) || addr4 END               
             || CASE WHEN addr5 IS NOT NULL THEN CHR(13)||CHR(10) || addr5 END AS Address
FROM addressdata
```

Answer (score 0):

An option would be using a dynamic SQL Select statement in order to profit `LISTAGG()` function containing Carriage return character along with the columns of the similar names(all those starts with `addr`) such as

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  v_str    VARCHAR2(1500);
  v_table  VARCHAR2(100):='ADDRESSDATA';
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG(c.column_name,'||'',''||CHR(13)||') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.column_id)
    INTO v_str
    FROM user_tab_cols c
   WHERE c.table_name = v_table   
     AND c.column_name LIKE 'ADDR%';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT '||v_str||
                     ' FROM '||v_table INTO v_str; 
                      
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_str);     
END;
/
```

Assuming your columns are sorted within the table as presented like `addr1`, `addr2`, `addr3` ..etc(*to consider the current ORDER BY clause*)

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=ad508ca43641a3152f75dd537c022590)</kbd>